# Title bar problem with Ambiance theme in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, panel, top

I was messing around, installing themes which went well.

However, I might have tweaked something that I can't roll back which is the top menu panel font as shown in this picture:

[image]

I am keeping a bright theme, so I can read title bar text, however I would like to have normal text back in case of the ambiance theme for example. 
I am new to Ubuntu.